# using UserProfile to restrict access in view

Tags: django, django-views

I have an app that displays client assets on html posting pages. Each client authorized to use the system is assigned a profile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.fullname

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['fullname']

    class Admin: 
        pass
```

and there's a model for the post pages:

```
class PostPage(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='POST')
    create_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    contact2 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    contact3 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    contact4 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
            return u'%s %s %s' % (self.client, self.job_number, self.job_name)

    class Admin: 
            pass
```

and finally, a very simple view function to display the pages:

```
def display_postings(request, job_number):
        records = PostPage.objects.filter(job_number=job_number)
        tpl = 'post_page.html'
        return render_to_response(tpl, { 'records': records })
```

The problem is, if you work for and access the system from "ACME" company, there's no logic in the view that would prevent you from viewing records for "BETAMAX" company in addition to your own. How can I modify my view so that if say, user.profile.company = "ACME" , but the request returns a record where PostPage.client = "BETAMAX", access to the record is denied? Additionally, can I have one company group, say user.profile.company = "MY_COMPANY" that has access to all records?

Answer (score 0):

Write a [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/) that checks the company of the `request.user` for the view. The code would look something like this:

```
def belongs_to_company(func):

    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        has_permissions = False
        # get current company
        ...

        # get user's list of company
        ...

        # if company not in user's list of company

        if not has_permissions:
            url = reverse('no_perms')
            return redirect(url)

        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

A better long term solution is to check out [Role Based Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) libraries like [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian)